# What is the purpose of the Events section of Photos on iOS?

Tags: ios, photos

I have an iPhone 4 and an iPad 3 each running iOS 6.1 (I don't have a Mac). On my iPad I have noticed that in Photos there is a tab labelled **Events**. This tab doesn't exist on my iPhone. The Events tab is filled with folders named with a date. Sometimes there is more than one folder with the same name.

I haven't been able to find clear documentation on the use of Events.

What is the purpose of Events in Photos? How do they differ from Albums and how do I use them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new event is created each time you transfer photos from your camera to your iPad, or from your computer to your iPad. Each event is the date when a group of photos was uploaded. As far as I know, unless you have iPhoto, there is no way to change these events names, or configure them at all.

Events differ from Albums in that they are created when you upload photos to your iPad. Albums must be created manually.

Events work best with iPhoto on OSX as iPhoto is remarkably "events-centric". When you import photos into iPhoto on Mac, it will automatically categorize them into "Events" (this is where Events can be named and settings can be adjusted). Then, when you sync the iPad with your Mac, these events are loaded onto your iPad.

Comment: Ok. I don't have a Mac though, just Windows & iOS. So in that context, how would one use Events?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. You have a good point. I edited my answer and perhaps it is a little more clear.